# Elegant way to change a variable according to several conditions?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement, case-when

I'm trying to change the variable "exposure" according to multiple conditions.

**For example:** If stimulus_content is "neg", and if condition is "neg", and if set is "A", then the content of the variable "exposure" should be changed to "long" for the lines in which stimulus_no is either X1, X2, ... or X5. The variable "exposure should be changed to "short" for the lines in which stimulus_no is either X6, X7, ... or X10. And so on...

I hope the code below makes the problem more clear.

First, this is the approximate dataset:

```
n <- 6
dataset <- data.frame(
participant = rep(1:n, each=40),
condition = rep(c("pos","neg"), each=40),
set = rep(c("A","B"), each=40),
stimulus_content = rep(c("pos","neg"), each=2),
stimulus_no = rep(c("X1","X10","X11","X12","X13","X14","X15","X16","X17","X18","X19","X2","X20","X3","X4","X5","X6","X7","X8","X9"), each=2),
exposure = NA)
```

**The first thing we tried is via a loop.** For the sake of simplicity, only one part of the loop is included. It doesn't return an error but it also doesn't do anything.

```
for (i in 1:length(longdat[,1])){
  if(longdat[i,"stimulus_content"] == "pos") { 
    if(longdat[i,"condition"] == "pos") {
      if(longdat[i,"set"] == "A") {     
        for(stimulus_no in c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5")){longdat[i,"exposure"] == "long"}
        for(stimulus_no in c("X6","X7","X8","X9","X10")){longdat[i,"exposure"] == "short"}
        for(stimulus_no in c("X11","X12","X13","X14","X15","X16","X17","X18","X19","X20")){longdat[i,"exposure"] == "none"}
      } else { #for condition = pos and set != A            
        for(stimulus_no in c("X11","X12","X13","X14","X15")){longdat[i,"exposure"] == "long"}
        for(stimulus_no in c("X16","X17","X18","X19","X20")){longdat[i,"exposure"] == "short"}
        for(stimulus_no in c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6","X7","X8","X9","X10")){longdat[i,"exposure"] == "none"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Next, we tried via **mutate and case_when**. This code does exactly what it's supposed to but it's almost 100 lines long! Please find an excerpt below.

```
longdat2 <- longdat %>%
  mutate(exposure = case_when(
    # Condition pos, set A
    stimulus_no=="X1" & stimulus_content=="pos" & condition=="pos" & set=="A" ~ "long",
    stimulus_no=="X2" & stimulus_content=="pos" & condition=="pos" & set=="A" ~ "long",
    # ...
    stimulus_no=="X9" & stimulus_content=="pos" & condition=="pos" & set=="A" ~ "short",
    stimulus_no=="X10" & stimulus_content=="pos" & condition=="pos" & set=="A" ~ "short",
    stimulus_no=="X11" & stimulus_content=="pos" & condition=="pos" & set=="A" ~ "none",
    # ... accordingly for condition pos and set B, and for condition neg and set A
    # and eventually for condition neg and set B
    stimulus_no=="X18" & stimulus_content=="neg" & condition=="neg" & set=="B" ~ "short",
    stimulus_no=="X19" & stimulus_content=="neg" & condition=="neg" & set=="B" ~ "short",
    stimulus_no=="X20" & stimulus_content=="neg" & condition=="neg" & set=="B" ~ "short",
  )
)
```

If someone manages to spot the error in the loop or could tell me a more succinct version of the second (or first) option, I'd be very grateful!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What language is this? R? Would be really helpful as tags. More helpful than both [tag:loops] and [tag:for-loop] or both [tag:if-statement] and [tag:conditional-statements].

Comment: `for(stimulus_no in c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5")){longdat[i,"exposure"] == "long"}` this looks wrong. Shouldn't this be `longdat[i, "exposure"] = "long"` or `longdat[i, "exposure"] <- "long"` (assignment, not comparison)?

Comment: Also, the loop body does not use the loop variable (`stimulus_no`)

Comment: Thank you for the tip @knittl 
I tried what you proposed in your second comment but the result hasn't changed. Would you mind explaining what you meant in your third comment, please? I didn't understand what you meant. Thanks

Comment: Your loop body does not contian the loop variable. All it does is execute the body N times. `for(stimulus_no in c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5")){longdat[i,"exposure"] == "long"}` simply executes `longdat[i,"exposure"] == "long"` 5 times, without making use of X1, X2, X3, X4, X5

Comment: Thank you @knittl for the explanations. I'm still learning how to do loops correctly. How would I have to write it if I wanted to do it correctly, if you don't mind? Thanks a lot, I'm very grateful for your time!

Comment: I'm not sure what the loop is supposed to do. If it should check one value against a set of values, you need a `contains` function or `in` operator in a condition, not a loop to execute its body multiple times.

Comment: There is two level of loop in your first solution. As @knittl said, you should replace the second level by a condition with a `in` operator. You sould also replace: `stimulus_no` by `longdat[i,"stimulus_no"]`: `if(longdat[i,"stimulus_no"] %in% c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5")){longdat[i,"exposure"] <- "long"}`

Comment: Thank you very much for your continued help @knittl and @barboulotte! I understand now what the problem was!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your second solution using `%in%` operator and inverse condition for the `else` part :

```
dataset2 <- dataset %>%
  mutate(exposure = case_when(
    # Condition pos, set A
    (stimulus_content=="pos" & condition=="pos" & set=="A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5") ~ "long",
    (stimulus_content=="pos" & condition=="pos" & set=="A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X6","X7","X8","X9","X10") ~ "short",
    (stimulus_content=="pos" & condition=="pos" & set=="A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X11","X12","X13","X14","X15","X16","X17","X18","X19","X20") ~ "none",
    # else
    !(stimulus_content=="pos" & condition=="pos" & set=="A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X11","X12","X13","X14","X15") ~ "long",
    !(stimulus_content=="pos" & condition=="pos" & set=="A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X16","X17","X18","X19","X20") ~ "short",
    !(stimulus_content=="pos" & condition=="pos" & set=="A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6","X7","X8","X9","X10") ~ "none"
  )
)
```

*EDIT*

For the solution with the loop :

```
dataset3 <- dataset
for (i in 1:length(dataset3[,1])){
  if(dataset3[i,"stimulus_content"] == "pos" & dataset3[i,"condition"] == "pos" & dataset3[i,"set"] == "A") {    
    if(dataset3[i,"stimulus_no"] %in% c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5")) {dataset3[i,"exposure"] <- "long"}
    if(dataset3[i,"stimulus_no"] %in% c("X6","X7","X8","X9","X10")) {dataset3[i,"exposure"] <- "short"}
    if(dataset3[i,"stimulus_no"] %in% c("X11","X12","X13","X14","X15","X16","X17","X18","X19","X20")){dataset3[i,"exposure"] <- "none"}
  } else {       
    if(dataset3[i,"stimulus_no"] %in% c("X11","X12","X13","X14","X15")) {dataset3[i,"exposure"] <- "long"}
    if(dataset3[i,"stimulus_no"] %in% c("X16","X17","X18","X19","X20")) {dataset3[i,"exposure"] <- "short"}
    if(dataset3[i,"stimulus_no"] %in% c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6","X7","X8","X9","X10")) {dataset3[i,"exposure"] <- "none"}
  }
}

compareDF::compare_df(dataset3, dataset2, rownames)
#> Error in stop_or_warn("The two data frames are the same!", stop_on_error): The two data frames are the same!
```

and to avoid the loop, like @g-grothendieck but closer to your code :

```
dataset4 <- within(dataset, {
  # Condition pos, set A
  exposure[(stimulus_content == "pos" & condition == "pos" & set == "A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5")] <- "long"
  exposure[(stimulus_content == "pos" & condition == "pos" & set == "A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X6","X7","X8","X9","X10")] <- "short"
  exposure[(stimulus_content == "pos" & condition == "pos" & set == "A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X11","X12","X13","X14","X15","X16","X17","X18","X19","X20")] <- "none"
  
  # else     
  exposure[!(stimulus_content == "pos" & condition == "pos" & set == "A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X11","X12","X13","X14","X15")] <- "long"
  exposure[!(stimulus_content == "pos" & condition == "pos" & set == "A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X16","X17","X18","X19","X20")] <- "short"
  exposure[!(stimulus_content == "pos" & condition == "pos" & set == "A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6","X7","X8","X9","X10")] <- "none"
})

compareDF::compare_df(dataset4, dataset2, rownames)
#> Error in stop_or_warn("The two data frames are the same!", stop_on_error): The two data frames are the same!
```

or

```
dataset5 <- within(dataset, {
  # Condition pos, set A
  exposure <- ifelse((stimulus_content == "pos" & condition == "pos" & set == "A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5"), "long", exposure)
  exposure <- ifelse((stimulus_content == "pos" & condition == "pos" & set == "A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X6","X7","X8","X9","X10"), "short", exposure)
  exposure <- ifelse((stimulus_content == "pos" & condition == "pos" & set == "A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X11","X12","X13","X14","X15","X16","X17","X18","X19","X20"), "none", exposure)
  
  # else     
  exposure <- ifelse(!(stimulus_content == "pos" & condition == "pos" & set == "A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X11","X12","X13","X14","X15"), "long", exposure)
  exposure <- ifelse(!(stimulus_content == "pos" & condition == "pos" & set == "A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X16","X17","X18","X19","X20"), "short", exposure)
  exposure <- ifelse(!(stimulus_content == "pos" & condition == "pos" & set == "A") & stimulus_no %in% c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6","X7","X8","X9","X10"), "none", exposure)
})

compareDF::compare_df(dataset5, dataset2, rownames)
#> Error in stop_or_warn("The two data frames are the same!", stop_on_error): The two data frames are the same!
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for the edit you provided! I have learned a lot thanks to you! Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

**1) grep** Create a `code` consisting of the columns to be matched pasted together and then use regular expressions to match them to get concise expressions.  No packages are used.  Note that [^A] will match any single character that is not A.  If you only have A and B you could use B instead.  X1[1-5] will match X11, ..., X15.   X[6-9]|X10 will match X6, ..., X10.  The $ matches the end of string.  Omit the `code <- NULL` line if you want to keep the `code` column.

```
dataset2 <- within(dataset, {
  code <- paste(stimulus_content, condition, set, stimulus_no)
  exposure[grep("pos pos A X[1-5]$", code)] <- "long"
  exposure[grep("pos pos A (X[6-9]|X10)$", code)] <- "short"
  exposure[grep("pos pos A (X1[1-9]|X20)$", code)] <- "none"
  exposure[grep("pos pos [^A] X1[1-5]$", code)] <- "long"
  exposure[grep("pos pos [^A] (X1[6-9]|X20)$", code)] <- "short"
  exposure[grep("pos pos [^A] (X[1-9]|X10)$", code)] <- "none"
  code <- NULL
})
```

**2) Between**  Another approach, also using only base R, is to define a `Between` function that checks that the non-numeric and numeric parts of its first argument separately assuming that the numeric part must be within the indicated range and the non-numeric part be equal to the fourth argument (which defaults to `"X"` so for conciseness we can omit it in the calls).  Then use `within` as shown:

```
Between <- function(x, lo, hi, alpha = "X") {
  nonno <- gsub("\\d", "", x)
  no = as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", x))
  no >= lo & no <= hi & nonno == alpha
}

dataset3 <- within(dataset, {

  cond1 <- stimulus_content == "pos" & condition == "pos" & set == "A"
  exposure[cond1 & Between(stimulus_no, 1, 5)] <- "long"
  exposure[cond1 & Between(stimulus_no, 6, 10)] <- "short"
  exposure[cond1 & Between(stimulus_no, 11, 20)] <- "none"

  cond2 <- stimulus_content == "pos" & condition == "pos" & set != "A"
  exposure[cond2 & Between(stimulus_no, 11, 15)] <- "long"
  exposure[cond2 & Between(stimulus_no, 16, 20)] <- "short"
  exposure[cond2 & Between(stimulus_no, 1, 10)] <- "none"

  cond1 <- cond2 <- NULL
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit and thank you for taking the time to answer my question! I didn't know about the between function!